# JRockit Mission Control does not capture Spring Bean methods invocations

Tags: spring, weblogic, profiler, jrockit

I am trying to profile my Spring Web app running on WebLogic 9.2

JRockit Mission Control 4.0 works perfectly except it doesn't capture Spring Beans method invocations. Are there any tricks to make it work?

Comment: Are you talking about the method profiler in the management console or the hot methods in JRA/Flight recorder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your Spring Web app loads the same class using different class loaders.

The method profiler only counts invocations for the first classloader it finds, not all of them.